# youtube embedded playback speed

Tags: javascript, youtube

I was wondering how exactly I'am able to change the playback speed of a youtube embedded video via javascript.

I can't seem to place it without it breaking the other events in the js.

My current code:

```
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: 'LdIjNVHCVsc',
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 0,
        modestbranding: 1,
        loop: 1,
        playlist: 'LdIjNVHCVsc'
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
      }
    }
  });
 }

 // Written by @labnol 
</script>
```

the code I currently have to change playback speed.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
    events: {
      'onReady': function(e){
        // e.target = player
        e.target.setPlaybackRate(0.5); // set to half speed
        e.target.playVideo(); // watch lolcats in slow motion :)
      },
    }
  });
}
```

For some reason it breaks the mute function of the original code, can you guys please give me a workaround. Thank you.

To reiterate, I want

```
        events: {
      'onReady': function(e){
        // e.target = player
        e.target.setPlaybackRate(0.5); // set to half speed
        e.target.playVideo(); // watch lolcats in slow motion :)
      },
    }
  });
}
```

where this is one is too.

```
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
      }
    }
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change Playback speed in you iOS Device. You need to change device user agent.

Please write below code in your player screen.

**//for video player speed rate**

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.45 Safari/535.19", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, following code will do your job.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player1, player2;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
        videoId: 'LdIjNVHCVsc',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            loop: 1,
            playlist: 'LdIjNVHCVsc'
        },
        events: {
            onReady: function(e) {
                e.target.mute();
            }
        }

    });

    player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 0
        },
        events: {
            onReady: function(e) {
                e.target.setPlaybackRate(0.5); // set to half speed
                e.target.playVideo(); // watch lolcats in slow motion :)
            },
        }
    });
}
```